# C# PSExec to execute multiple path from StreamReader parsing

Tags: c#, streamreader, psexec

I'm trying to learn how C# could read and parsing multiple line from text file using streamReader and afterward process each of line with PSExec

Inside cocomand.txt have multiple line example 
c:/command1.cmd
c:/command2.bat
c:/command3.cmd

```
        private static void calleachline()
        {
            string pathx = @"c:\cocomand.txt";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(pathx, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                while ((!reader.EndOfStream))
                    {

                    System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"psexec.exe";
                    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\localhost";
                    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cmd.Start();

                    if (!cmd.WaitForExit(cmd2))
                    {
                        ExecutePSKill(cmd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
```

Trying to understand from few thread but with my lack knowledge seems this still doesn't work

Comment: You don't call `ExecutePsexec` at all in your loop.  I think you intended to.  I believe that it should have been within the `foreach` call, but can you clarify?  There's a lot in the provided code that just doesn't represent what you're describing you want to do.

Comment: you're right but i'm getting confused . basically what I intend just parsing each line of cocomand.txt into line by line then call each of it by PSExec .